# asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I want to hide a column of GridView based on a condition. How can I access the column in C# code?

```
 if() // condition
 {
     // Disable code here. ?????
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple man..

```
Grid.Columns[columnIndex].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Can I use column name instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Akhtar 
You are correct.

```
grdUsers.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

This code remove first column of gridview on displaying side.